# Adding all the tk.Button objects to a list to config

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter, tkinter-entry

So I'd like to add all the tk.Button(and entry) objects in an entire program to a list. (so that I can change the colours of every button though iterate and config)

I'm creating a bunch of tkinter frames like this:

```
class AppClass(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):


        # Initialising Tkinter
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, 'test-program')
        tk.Tk.geometry(self, '800x480') 

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.background_theme = '2'
        self.background_theme_to_be_written_to_file  = '2'

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (HomePage,
                  SecondName,
                  ThirdName):

            frame = F(container, self)


            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

            frame.configure(background=background_page)


        self.show_frame(HomePage)
```

## ...

```
app = AppClass()

app.mainloop()
app = None
exit()
```

Ideas? I know **`.winfo_children()`** can select all the objects in a page - can we select all the objects in the program?

**

at the moment I'm trying to make something like this work - oddly it's only changing one button on the screen (There are 4):

```
parent.list_of_objects_in_parent = tk.Button.winfo_children(parent)

print(parent.list_of_objects_in_parent)

for entry in parent.list_of_objects_in_parent:
    entry.config(bg="pink")
```

**quick update:

I kind of have a partial solution:

```
self.bind("<<ShowFrame>>", self.on_show_frame)
```

...

```
def on_show_frame(self, event):
    self.list_of_objects_in_parent = tk.Button.winfo_children(self)
    print(self.list_of_objects_in_parent)
    for entry in self.list_of_objects_in_parent:
        if type(entry) == type(self.button_to_go_to_home_page):
            entry.config(bg="pink")
            print("working")
```

Comment: If I understand correctly what you want, you just have to create a list in your class and make a function which create your widget and add it to this list

Comment: You could at the very least select all objects, recursively assuming `winfo_children` works the way you say.

Comment: Are you unable to create the widgets as in a list of widget objects, like `for i in range(10): btn[i] = tk.Button(parent, text="button" + num)`?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible.

You can simply call `.winfo_children()` on the `Tk()` window which will return a list of all widgets in the top level of the window which you can iterate over, see below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def command():
    for i in root.winfo_children():
        i.configure(bg="pink")

entry = Entry(root)
button = Button(root, text="Ok", command=command)

entry.pack()
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

If you have multiple layers of widgets (IE, `Frame`s containing widgets, `Toplevel` widgets) then you need to add some sort of recursion in order to get **ALL** of the widgets in your program, we can do this with something like the below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def command():
    x = root.winfo_children()
    for i in x:
        if i.winfo_children():
            x.extend(i.winfo_children())
        i.configure(bg="pink")

entry = Entry(root)
button = Button(root, text="Ok", command=command)

frame = Frame(root)
entry2 = Entry(frame)

top = Toplevel(root)
entry3 = Entry(top)

entry.pack()
entry2.pack()
entry3.pack()
button.pack()
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```